# Prolem using urbanairship Provider android

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

I am using urbanairship to show notifications. I have updated my Android SDK to latest update and it starts showing error related to urbanairship provider and it was working fine with older version.

```
05-22 17:54:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(575): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 17:54:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(575): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipProvider
05-22 17:54:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(575):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4289)
05-22 17:54:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(575):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4041)
05-22 17:54:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(575):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3995)
05-22 17:54:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(575):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:127)
05-22 17:54:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(575):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1217)
05-22 17:54:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(575):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-22 17:54:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(575):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4508)
05-22 17:54:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(575):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 17:54:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(575):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-22 17:54:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(575):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
05-22 17:54:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(575):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
05-22 17:54:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(575):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 17:54:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(575): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipProvider
05-22 17:54:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(575):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
05-22 17:54:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(575):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-22 17:54:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(575):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-22 17:54:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(575):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4274)
05-22 17:54:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(575):  ... 12 more
```

I am using urbanairship-lib-2.1.4.jar in my project. Is there any compatibility issue or what?

Comment: The same bloody error. Have no clue how to solve that :(( Apparently the problem is in new ADT since this error came up right after I got updated

Comment: Hey try that answer given below it is really working :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yey! Just found a solution for that!
The problem is in `Android Private Libraries` which were introduced with latest update. For some reason by default they are ticked *off* in project properties.

Just go to the `Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export` and check `Android Private Libraries` . This solved my problem.